# If Variable 1 is defined, variable 2 must be empty and vice versa in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bit of a problem with a getopts construct.
I define multiple variables via getopts and have some conditions I have to check before going further in the script.

The user shouldn't be able to define two special options together (`-t` for `$target` and `-tg` for `$targetgroup`). So what I'm looking for is a construct that checks:

- if `$target` is defined, then `$targetgroup` must be empty, and
- if `$targetgroup` is defined `$target` must be empty.

I've done a workaround with `[[ -z $target ]]`, `[[ -n $targetgroup ]]` and checking the exit codes, but I think this approach is just simply wrong.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing a 1-of-n condition like this, we can use parameter expansion with the `:+` modifier.  `${target:+1}` expands to `1` only when `$target` is non-empty.  So you can test that `"${target:+1}${targetgroup:+1}"` doesn't contain more than one `1`:

```
if [[ ${target:+1}${targetgroup:+1} == 11* ]]
then
    echo 'Error: it is invalid to specify both -t and -tg' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

For this particular case (where there are only two mutually-exclusive variables), we don't need the `*` in the pattern.  It's there so that you can easily add more options that must not be used together with either of these two, without needing to change anything else.

You could also use it where you're allowed up to any *n* of a set of arguments; to do so, you would write *n*+1 `1`s in the match string.

If you want *exactly* one of the two options to be supplied, then change the test to `!= 1`.

Comment: No need for `=~`, plain `=` or `==` should work as well.

Comment: @TobySpeight: You can still use a pattern, `[[ ... == *111* ]]`.

Comment: @choroba - I've edited again, with your suggestion to use a pattern match.  I like it better now.  Thanks again for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider merging two (or more) mutually exclusive flags into a single option that takes an argument. That is, instead of `-t` and `-tg` being separate arguments, define `-x <arg>`, where `<arg>` can be either `t` or `tg`.

```
while getopts "x:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    x) case $OPTARG of
         t) ... ;;
         tg) ... ;;
         *) echo "Invalid argument for -x: $OPTARG" ;;
       sac ;;
    ...
  esac
done
```